# WordPress site duplicated and now makes conflict

Tags: wordpress

I have duplicate site "A" and makes copy in diffrent folder on same server using duplicator, and now what is happening that sometimes one site is working and second one doesnt. I have tried to makes changes in wp-config and define on both sites their urls using:

```
define('WP_HOME','');
define('WP_SITEURL','');
```

But it doesn't help.

They use different databases of course. And it looks like sometimes one site is taking resources from the second one, and once the second site taking it from 1st. Maybe you have an idea of how to define, the exact path of all folders.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out that duplicator doesn't change all the links in database propely, so I had to change them directly in database.